# How to check if the selenium chrome window is closed python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, window, instagram

I am making a desktop assistant and it can open and login to my Instagram. But when I close the Instagram chrome window, the loop doesn't end. So how can I check if the window is closed and end the loop?

```
class Instagram:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input').send_keys("username")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]").send_keys("pass")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()

        sleep(4)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div/div/button").click()
        sleep(4)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]").click()
        sleep(4)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]").click()
        
        sleep(5)
        while x == 1:
            sleep(10)
x = 1

if "open instagram" in query:
    Instagram()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the user closes the window you can figure that out by catching a `WebDriverException` when trying to interact with the driver.
For example you could add

```
try:
    self.driver.get('example.com')
except WebDriverException: 
    print("user has closed the window")
    # do something with that 
    break
```

to the loop at the end of `__init__`

Also, the value of `x` never changes in your code, so it is an endless loop. Except you change the value somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can check:

**#1**
First, import `from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException`. Then, do this:

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

def isDriverClosed():
    try:
        driver.get("google.com")
        return False
    except WebDriverException:
        print("webdriver closed by user")
        return True
```

**#2**
Simply check the length of the number of tabs open. If the length is 0, that means no tabs are open, which means that the window is closed.:

```py
def isDriverClosed():
    global driver
    if driver:
        if not driver.window_handles:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: these are great suggestions. thanks!